Windows 10 монитор не выводит изображение
В системник воткнуты монитор по dp и монитор по hdmi. dp монитор выбран как основной.
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/CBIdAsuf5Yo
При включении монитора иконки переходят на него - есть понимание что монитор включился, но сам монитор не показывает рабочий стол
видно три монитора 
но при отключении монитора с проблемой видно 2 устройства

но при этом при отключении телевизора что подключен по hdmi он из списка не пропадает
при подключении только одного косяного монитра - все ок

"но сам монитор не показывает рабочий стол" - а что показывает, вообще просто черный?

ссылка на ютуб. как будто кабель отключен

Ссылки на внешние ресурсы не приветствуются. Вся информация должна быть в вопросе. Сам монитор то исправен?

да. исправен. вполне
